# Attach wpf view dll to existing wpf exe

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, prism, wpftoolkit

I have a WPF executable and I wish to make provisions to it, so that later,
someone from outside might modify or add another window or page
using dll totally separate from my solution.

For short, I wish to make my wpf windows or pages pluggable. How do I do this?

Comment: You already have your `EXE` or you're creating one from scratch? If I understood you correctly, you want to make a Library (DLL), right?

Answer (score 1):

Prism's support modular, on-demand-loading of modules and other parts of your application, in it's core.

you can use [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) framework to make pluggable modules (windows and pages), as it's fully integrated with Prism.

You can find examples and more information in the following resources:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188054/An-Introduction-to-Managed-Extensibility-Framework

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37579/Managed-Extensibility-Framework-Part-2

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432069/Simple-MEF-Application-for-Beginners

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232868/MEF-Features-with-Examples